# New row when clicking DataGridViewButton

Tags: c#, datagridview

I've got a datagridview with a button in a column to generate the next ID within the current line.
I'd like to have the button create an empty row, just like when you enter text into the last row.

I've tried different variations of adding a new row, which didn't work since the datagridview uses a datasource.

```
if (e.RowIndex == dgv.Rows.Count - 1)
{
    //dgv.Rows.InsertCopy(dgv.Rows.Count - 1, dgv.Rows.Count);
}
```

how can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your data source?

Comment: @WSC it's linked to a dataset

Comment: I'm assuming by dataset you mean a datatable within a dataset... Have you tried inserting a record into the underlying datatable?

Comment: @WSC That worked ... kind of. Can you Write that as the solution (with bindingSorce.AddNew() )